# Lodash Debounce sends request without callback React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, lodash, debouncing

I'm having problems with setting up lodash debounce in the function to make an API request. For some reason callback doesn't happen and the value sends every time I type.

```
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const debouncedSave = debounce((nextValue) => dispatch(movieActions.getMovies(nextValue), 1000));
    debouncedSave(value);
  };
```

I'm using material ui and have this in return:

```
<Autocomplete
  onInputChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: why you are calling debouncedSave(nextValue); ? 
you can `debounce(() => dispatch(movieActions.getMovies(nextValue), 1000));` use like this

Comment: You are creating a new debounced function every time the onChange handler is called. You need to define it outside of the handler.

Comment: @trixn I see, however it still does a request every time now that the debounceSave is outside of handleChange function

Comment: Is there anything else that triggers a re-render when you type something in the autocomplete? You likely also need to memorise it using `useCallback` so it will also not be recreated on every render.

Comment: I tried running it through useCallback and it doesn't make requests at all now `const debouncedSave = useCallback( () => {
      debounce((nextValue) => dispatch(movieActions.getMovies(nextValue), 1000))
    }, [], )`

Comment: consider using `useMemo` instead of `useCallback` 


`const debouncedSave = useMemo( () => debounce((nextValue) => dispatch(movieActions.getMovies(nextValue), 1000)), [dispatch] ); `

and calling it in the your function as: `const handleChange = (event) => { const { value: nextValue } = event.target;    debouncedSave(nextValue); } `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debounced function is created multiple times for each change event and that causes the problem. I will use a simplified example with a simple `input` and a `console.log` instead of your `dispatch`, but you can apply the solution to your case as well.

The simplest solution would be to move the `debouncedSave` declaration outside your component.

```js
const debouncedSave = debounce((nextValue) => console.log(nextValue), 1000);

export default function App() {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    debouncedSave(value);
  };

  return <input onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```

or else if you want to keep the debounced function declaration inside your component you can use a `ref`, to create and use the same instance each time, no matter the re-renders:

```js
export default function App() {
  const debouncedSaveRef = useRef(
    debounce((nextValue) => console.log(nextValue), 1000)
  );

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    debouncedSaveRef.current(value);
  };

  return <input onChange={handleChange} />;
}
```